# Why is an app built for api 23 using old black style dialogs not new white style?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I'm trying to add a dialog to an old app and have used the FireMissilesDialogFragment code from Android's documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

According to the documentation the dialog should look like this:

[image]

But when I run the code it instead looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code, its identical to that in the documentation except for the strings:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("The message")
                .setPositiveButton("Positive button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Negative button", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
    fragment.show(fm, "What is this parameter for");
```

The app is built using API 23 running on a device with M.

I created a brand new app from an Android Studio template and pasted in the above code, this time it was white like the documentation (but was missing the thin grey divider lines).

The app is a very old app being updated for M.However its minSDK and compileSDK have been set to 23, what is it about it that could be making it display dialogs in the old black style not the new white style?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your App doesnt have the Holo Light style.
You can change it easily in your values/styles.xml file, it should look like this :

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">  //Or android:Theme.Holo.Light
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: There wasn't an existing values/styles/xml file, but after creating one and adding that Holo style it didn't have any effect on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Define your own style (like suggested by Ahmet Kazaman) but name your custom style to something different than **AppBaseTheme**.
I had similar issues with styles on API-23 when I named my style as **AppBaseTheme**.
Then, in your manifest file in application tag, do: **android:theme="@style/YourCustomStyleName"**